# Vbulletin fatal error / php

Tags: php, vbulletin

I installed a modification for my vbulletin suite and got this error

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /var/www/forum/includes/class_hook.php on line 57
```

Apparently some users have this error when using the mod
with vbadvanced, but theres no support given.

Maybe someone can figure it out.
I don't have any php-knowledge, so i appologize in advance

This is line 53 - 58

```
53  * Sets the plugin list array
54  */
55  function set_pluginlist(&$pluginlist)
56  {
57      $this->pluginlist =& $pluginlist;
58  }
```

I hope someone can help me, also it's not very much information :/

Comment: @JaredFarrish it is inside a VERY LARGE plugin file, so it is not possible to check if it is called via an object. BTW, the plugin developer had given a link to download the corrected files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same problem seems to be addressed. Try checking out: [VBulletin Forum](http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=279463).

Let me quote from there:

> I've uploaded a fix for the vBAdvanced issue, please re-download the zip file and re-upload `/dbtech/livewall/hooks/process_templates_complete.php`

The link to that single post: http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showpost.php?s=0de19e68ada2bc70d3698e851f0cce9e&p=2306225&postcount=12

Hope it is useful! :)

Comment: Yes, thanks i got that via google to at the moment and trying it out, but that is not the plugin i've installed. The plugin i got is "DBTech: Advanced Post Thanks / Like". Let's see if this fixes it, though

Comment: Yeah, sure, if not, just post the full code in some good sites like pastebin or something, so that people can debug and get it for you.

Comment: Oh wow, seems a bit weird. But i copied the file that was provided in that thread in the direction from the modification i've installed and (even tho it's a complete different mod) it works now :D Ty for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

Re-upload the modification you used in ASCII mode.